# @ngstack/code-editor Implementation problem

Tags: angular, code-editor

I'm trying to implement a code editor in the angular app.
I follow the steps on their page https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngstack/code-editor
However, as soon as I open the page I got the "ReferenceError: monaco is not defined"
Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Any update to this?